# Has anyone implement DITA 1.2 Subject scheme in their work?

Tags: dita

I would like to know if there is anyone who has implemented the subjectscheme maps of DITA1.2 in their work? If yes, can you please break-up the example to show:

- how to do it?
- when not to use it?

I am aware of the theory behind it, but I am yet to implement the same and I wanted to know if there are things I must keep in mind during the planning and implementation phase.

Comment: Kris Eberlien has been doing a lot of subject scheme work. She might be able to point you in the right direction if you don't get results here. http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/dita-users/message/30888

Comment: What do you want to use subjectScheme for?

Answer (score 1):

An example is here:

[How to use DITA subjectSchemes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101188/how-to-use-dita-subjectschemes)

The DITA 1.2 spec also has a good example (3.1.5.1.1).

What you can currently do with subject scheme maps is:

- define a taxonomy
- bind the taxonomy to a profiling or flagging attribute, so that it the attribute only takes a value that you have defined
- filter or flag elements that have a defined value with a DITAVAL file.

Advantage 1: Since you have a taxonomy, filtering a parent value also filters its children, which is convenient.

Advantage 2: You can fully define and thus control the list of values, which prevents tag bloat.

Advantage 3: You can reuse the subject scheme map in many topic maps, in the usual modular DITA way, so you can apply the same taxonomies anywhere.

These appear to be the main uses for a subject scheme map at present.

The only disadvantages I have found is that I can think of other hypothetical uses for subject scheme maps such as faceted browsing, but I don't think any implementation exists. The DITA-OT doesn't have anything like that yet anyway.